# Why is my ImageSource Binding not updated?

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, mvvm

I'm trying to dynamically bind an Image Source in XAML to an URI in `ViewModel` (MVVM). This works fine for the initial URI, the picture "C:\tmp\Test.png" is shown. But if I set another URI to `ImageURI` in `ViewModel` the picture is not updated. Can anyone help me?

XAML:

```
<Image x:Name="UserImage" Stretch="Fill" Grid.Row="0">
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage CreateOptions="IgnoreImageCache" UriSource="{Binding ImageURI, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

ViewModel:

```
public string imageURI = "C:\\tmp\\Test.png";
public string ImageURI
{
    get
    {
        return imageURI;
    }
    set
    {
        imageURI = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("ImageURI");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

BitmapImage implements ISupportInitialize. This means that property changes  are ignored after initialization. Changing the Binding's source property has no effect.

You should directly bind the Image's `Source` property. Built-in automatic type conversion will create a BitmapFrame behind the scenes.

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageURI}" .../>
```

Setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit` and `Mode=TwoWay` on the Binding is pointless.

If you need to explicitly create a BitmapImage (e.g. one where the IgnoreImageCache option is set), write an appropriate Binding Converter.

Comment: Thank You! But unfortunately nothing changed. The image is loaded once at program start but after this the image remains as it is. When I debugged I could see that the handler of OnPropertyChanged is null:

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }

What could the problem be?

Comment: Did you probably forget the INotifyPropertyChanged interface in your ViewModel class declaration?

Comment: No I didn't. Other bindings in my ViewModel work properly. When I set the Image.Source in code behind the update works. But I don't want to break the MVVM pattern.

Comment: The new ImageURI is another absolute path?

Comment: Yes it is. Mhhh? Didn't found some working code in the net. Can't believe WPF does not support such basic functionality...

Comment: It does, of course. There must be something else wrong in your code.

Answer (score -1):

Pretty old question here with no solution. Sooo since i had a similar problem and used a slightly different approach, here is my solution:

Use a converter which returns a BitmapImage in this way:

```cs
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    BitmapImage error = new();
    error.BeginInit();
    // OnLoad will give you errors just with the start of your application and 
    // and won't hide somewhere in your log
    error.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    error.UriSource = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Images/error.png");
    error.EndInit();
    error.Freeze();

    return error;
}
```

The binding:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource enumAnalyzerStatusConverter}, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

The `OnLoad` option will give an error on startup if something is bad with your image like the path. Remember to set the image in your project explorer to `Ressource`.